# Perl Extract float number from within a string of text using regex

Tags: regex, string, perl

Although seems simple - I did not a good example of perl code using regex which extracts float out of a (any) string like the following:

```
my $str = "process.pl: process workflow took 2.41153311729431 seconds.";
my $processTime = parseFloatFromString($str);
print "$processTime\n";

and gives 2.41
```

I would like to extract a less precise value - say with 2 decimal points.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

There are two steps to this:

1. Extracting the floating point numbers from your string
2. Converting those numbers to your required precision

Step 1 is harder than you might think, so I recommend using a ready-made regex (like the one I've used here from [`Regexp::Common`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Common)).

```
use Regexp::Common;

my @floats = $string =~ /($RE{num}{real})/g;
```

Then you can use `sprintf()` or `printf()` to change the precision.

```
printf "%0.2f\n" for @floats;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the number using a regular expression and print it using [`printf`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/printf.html) as follows:

```
my ( $number ) = ( $str =~ /(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)/ );
printf "%.2f", $number;
```

The code above is simplified for clarity. You should also handle the case when the pattern does not match (no numbers), e.g.:

```
$number = 0 unless defined $number;
```

Adjust the regular expression according to your needs, unless you want to handle all possible representations of a floating point number.

<sub>If you really want to handle all possible inputs, then use a library as Dave Cross suggested. But since *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow..."*, I won't suggest any library. Besides, it looks like you are simply learning Perl and willing to learn how stuff is actually done using the Perl regular expressions. So I suggest you to go on, read [`perlre`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html), and then consider whether you really need a library.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

A bare numeric parse is simply this `(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)`

To modify it to accept 0-2 decimal places it would be

https://regex101.com/r/n3gAFC/1

`(?:\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})?|\.\d{1,2})`

Expanded

```
 (?:
      \d+ 
      (?: \. \d{0,2} )?
   |  \. \d{1,2} 
 )
```

Note there is no boundary specification for this.
So, it has to be modified to be used globally.

Generally, you can just add a `\d*` after the regex and include a capture
group.
This will capture what you need, *and* match what you don't need thereby
progressing the match position for the next number.

`(\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})?|\.\d{1,2})\d*`

***Usage***

If you only want to change pre-existing float strings,
you can change the regex to require a decimal point.
It's the same as the general at the top, remove the option
on it's cluster group will not match digits only.

This `(\d+(?:\.\d*)|\.\d+)`

If you use this, you can take advantage of *sprint()* in the substitute form.
This will do it all at once without having to extract, re-assemble or otherwise
trash the existing string.

You have many options to choose from, this is just one.

Perl

```
 use strict;
 use warnings;

 my $str = "process.pl: process 3 workflow took .0 days, 2.41153311729431 secs, 2411.53311729431 ms, 2411533.11729431 us.";

 # To print without modify the string
 print $str =~ s/(\d+(?:\.\d*)|\.\d+)/sprintf("%0.2f",$1)/erg, "\n";

 # Or, print and modify the string at the same time
 print $str = $str =~ s/(\d+(?:\.\d*)|\.\d+)/sprintf("%0.2f",$1)/erg, "\n";
```

Output

```
 process.pl: process 3 workflow took 0.00 days, 2.41 secs, 2411.53 ms, 2411533.12 us.
 process.pl: process 3 workflow took 0.00 days, 2.41 secs, 2411.53 ms, 2411533.12 us.
```

Comment: There's no need to "match what you don't need"

Comment: In `(?:\.\d{0,2})?|\.\d{1,2})` the second alternation will never match because it will always have been matched by the first.

Comment: @Borodin - `There's no need to "match what you don't need"` could you clarify that statement ?  `(?:\.\d{0,2})?|\.\d{1,2})` where did you get this regex from ??

Comment: @Borodin - Let me help you `(?: \. \d{0,2} )?  |  \. \d{1,2} =    )  <-- Unbalanced  ')'`

Answer (score -1):

1. Like Brodin indicated a/ extract the field then b/ present it properly. If the output is consistent, I'd just split
   it:

> ```
> $procTime=split(' ',$str)[4]; # extract ... Thx to Sinan for improving this
> printf "process time: %7.2f\n", $procTime; # present
> ```

2. Fix the root of the problem! Change the original output to produce 2-decimal
   point. You would not have to do extra work of extracting & presenting it properly

Comment: `(split ' ', $str)[4]`

Comment: @SinanÜnür: Better still `(split ' ', $str, 6)[4]`. The last I heard, perl optimises `my (undef, undef, undef, $f4) = split ' ', $str` but the equivalent list slice isn't improved.

Comment: @kybof: It was [**Dave Cross** who suggested that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44572098/622310), not me.

Comment: @kybof: [**SinanÜnür** meant what he wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44571930/perl-extract-float-number-from-within-a-string-of-text-using-regex#comment76171599_44576656) `(split ' ', $str)[4]` is correct; `(split / /, $str)[4]` is not.